# Site accessed by Intel Mac OS X and iPhone OS at the same time

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, network, http

I have created my own logging in a PHP script on my website. While doing this, I record a timestamp, IP address and HTTP referrer. I notice that I often have two hits as follows where it looks like an iPhone and a Mac are accessing my site at roughly the same time from the same IP address. Can someone explain what is happening here?

> ['2019-06-23 02:47:26pm', '172.117.xxx.xxx', 'Lakewood, California,
>   United States', '', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6)
>   AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko)']
>
> ['2019-06-23 02:47:28pm', '172.117.xxx.xxx', 'Lakewood, California,
>   United States', '', 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_1_3 like
>   Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0
>   Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1']

> ['2019-06-23 03:09:04pm', '95.44.xxx.xxx', 'Drogheda, Louth, Ireland',
>   '', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6)
>   AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko)']
>
> ['2019-06-23 03:09:07pm',
>   '95.44.xxx.xxx', 'Drogheda, Louth, Ireland', '', 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone;
>   CPU iPhone OS 12_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1']

Comment: If you have access to a Mac, try accessing your website from within an iPhone Simulator and see if you get a similar log entry.

Comment: It might be to do with Handoff, where you can access a website on one device and then continue browsing on another, as long as they are both unlocked and nearby each other.

Comment: @Lizzan But the actual php script is being run twice within a couple of seconds of each other so I dont think this is about handing off. Plus it seems to be happening with a large proportion of the iphone/mac accesses to my site.

Comment: @Baz I just figured that maybe there was an access made in the background to prepare the devices for handoff. But I really don't know, it was just an idea. Hopefully you'll get better answers.

Comment: @Lizzan  No worries, thanks for your input!